# how to set color on text Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular 5 with material.

I can use the property color on material element.

What's the equivalent way to set color on text?

For example:

```
<h1 class="mat-subheading-1" color="accent" >Via Del Corso, 100, ROMA</h1>
```

Does not work.

I don't want to implement a custom css class for that since I want to use the angular material theming.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot do that because color is probably a specific input property to material components.

Take a look at [Theming Docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme)

Once you have followed that you can easily do this below:

In your app.style.scss file include

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@import './app.theme';

.accent-color {
  color: mat-color($accent) !important;
}
```

Then just use the class in your header like so:

```
<h1 class="mat-subheading-1 accent-color">Via Del Corso, 100, ROMA</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks. I came up with the same solution that it's ok because is connected to the theme.

Comment: @ChristianMatthew saying it's out of date without a link, reference, or updated answer doesn't really improve the current situation.